# Why do my sprites that have curves appear jagged in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am using a sprite (SKSpriteNode) that's 400px by 400px. Whether I scale this image or not, it does not have smooth curves. However, when I create an SKLabelNode, the text is very very smooth. Why does this happen and what can I do to correct it? Extra info: I'm using Pixelmator and Gimp for image creation.

Comment: you'd need anti-aliasing to reduce jagged edges but i think it's not supported by sprite kit. I believe few mobile games use aa since it's quite performance intensive, plus on retina devices the resolution is high enough to not notice it nearly as much - assuming properly sized images with unscaled sprites

Comment: This is for OSX though. Yeah, I looked into the anti-aliasing before and no dice. How is it that the labels are so nice! Even the default sprite (the spaceship) looks ok.